# Exception detail

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I am new to .net ..Is there any difference between exception and Exception in .net I received error while using 'exception'..

Comment: You'll have to explain more. What was this error, and where did your recieve it?

Comment: Error 4 The type or namespace name 'exception' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is case sensitive, while VB.NET is not.  If your class/page/control is in C#, then there is a difference between `Exception` and `exception`, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

C# is case sensitive (Exception != exception) - in the BCL (Base Class Library), there is an [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) class, but there is no `exception` class.

Your question however is not very clear - can you post the relevant parts of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using c#, the keyword Exception is case-sensitive. If you intend to use the class then you need to use the Exception class than in lowercase.